# How to use dynamic url in nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working with nextjs,I am fetching image(via api),Right now i am getting
"Full image path"(for example,"https//myurl.com/image/imagename.jpg") so i am fetching without
any problem,but i want to know that if i have only "image name"(for example,"imagename.jpg")
so how can we fetch in front end ? in other words how can i pass "url/hostname" before imagename ?
Should i create seprate "component" and mention "host url" and fetch whereever i want OR Should
i create "variable" like following code or is there another way ?

```
class Company extends React.Component {
    const orig = 'http://anyurl.com';

    state = {
        trending: []
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://myurl.com/apipath',
        )
          .then(res => {
            const trending = res.data;
            this.setState({ trending });
          })
      }

    render() {
            return 
                (

                    <img src={post.image} /> 
                );      
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable `baseURL` that contains a constant path to your backend URL. This would be static. The only dynamic part is your imageFileName. You can store this in state or get it from props or where ever you are getting the `imagename.jpg` from.

When you want to define some constant values like style or image URLs then it's always better to define that outside of component. It will become global values and available inside each function/class of that file.

config/urlConfig.js

```
export const urlConfig={
    baseURL: 'http://myurl.com/image/'
}
```

//Your component

```
import { urlConfig } from 'path/to/your/config/urlConfig';
class Company extends React.Component {
    state = {
        trending: [],
        imageFileName: 'imagename.jpg'   // Assign any value to this
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(urlConfig.baseURL + this.state.imageFileName,
        )
          .then(res => {
            const trending = res.data;
            this.setState({ trending });
          })
      }

    render() {
            return 
                (

                    <img src={post.image} /> 
                );      
            );
        }
```

Comment: whenever i am trying to use "const" , its giving me following error

"Unexpected token `orig`. Expected * for generator, private key, identifier or async"

Comment: Ideally you can create a separate config file with file contents as: `export const urlConfig={baseURL: 'http://myurl.com/image/'}`. And use it as `urlConfig.baseURL`.
Ofcourse import the config like `import { urlConfig } from 'path/to/your/constants/file'`;

Comment: you mean, me should create "separate component" and use in "class component"(current file), am i right ?\

Comment: Actually in "axios.get" i want to use "another api" (which giving me data ) not just "urlconfig",So i want to know how can i use "component" after import (in front of img tag) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the base URL, you can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the same.
For Example:

```
const orig = 'https://myurl.com/apipath';
const imageName = 'image1.jpg';
const imgUrl = `${orig}/${imageName}`
```

Comment: i tried with your code but i am getting following error

Unexpected token `orig`. Expected * for generator, private key, identifier or async

Comment: This Error is not related to your question. All the above code will do is create a URL for you based on values of imageNames. Please provide a detailed info of the error, alongwith your implementation.

Comment: i already mentioned "error detail" and already explain my current "code"

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate Variable and add them like this ${} in string literal. then you will use dynamic fetching.

Comment: can you explain this because i dont know how to create seprate variable in class component , i tried but not worked for me

Comment: const orig = 'http://anyurl.com';

    state = {
        trending: []
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://myurl.com/apipath/${this.orig}',
        )
          .then(res => {
            const trending = res.data;
            this.setState({ trending });
          })
      }

Comment: you can use this.variable_name in class component

Comment: whenever i use "const" its giving me error "Unexpected token `orig`. Expected * for generator, private key, identifier or async"